# leaderboard sql query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm implementing a leaderboard for our group project.

this is my query for counting the number of status userid 2 have in the table.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(content) FROM status WHERE userid=2 ";
```

now, how could i query the userid with most number of status?

example table

```
||  content  ||  userid  ||
||     x     ||     1    ||
||    xx     ||     1    ||
||     y     ||     2    ||
||    yy     ||     2    ||
||   yyy     ||     2    ||
||     z     ||     3    ||
```

with result

```
1st = 2 with 3 status
2nd = 1 with 2 status
3rd = 3 with 1 status
```

what will i do to limit the result? what if i only need the top 5?

in relation to this problem

i was thinking of adding another column(number_of_status) in the user table instead of this multiple queries... which is better?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do this with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS status_count
  FROM status
  GROUP BY userid
  ORDER BY status_count DESC
  LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a GROUP BY query, and [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(content) as statuses
FROM status
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY statuses DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: thanks@DANJ! however when i print this using mysql_fetch_array it skips the first query. help pls? thanks!